# ASP.NET Page does't show code behind code when clicking on Design code

Tags: asp.net

Page does't show code behind code when clicking on Design code  and also code behind code display error as control not found

Below code display error : System Error

```
<%@Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register" %>
```

I don't why it fetches this type of error ,please help me

Code Behind:

```
using System;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason for which the designer cannot open the code behind is because it cannot find the associated code behind file specified `Inherits="Register"`

Make sure you have a public class named `Register` that must be  `Partial` as well

make sure also the the code behind file name is named as `Register.aspx.cs`

Answer (score 0):

must check make Inherits attributed in design and code file path

Comment: checked it's correct  Design code :<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register" %>
Code Behind:using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I totally misunderstood your question.

If your Register.aspx file looks like this:

```
<%@Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register" %>
```

The Register.aspx.cs should look (at least) like this:

```
using System;

namespace YourDefaultNamespace
{
    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I notice that you don't have a namespace in the `Inherits` attribute of your `<%@ Page %>` directive. It should have the same namespace as your codebehind file. In my example that's `YourDefaultNamespace`, so my `<%@ Page %>` directive should be this:

```
<%@Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourDefaultNamespace.Register" %>
```

Comment: Thanks but i m using code behind page and i not going to code behind ,it goes directly to design source code but it's not happen in last day so please help